# How to stretch multiple lines to x axis in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I am trying to show multiple lines in [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/).

So I was able to the multiple lines like the first chart. But it doesn't make sense to me.

What is ideal is that all of the lines should be stretched to the x-axis like in the second chart.

X axis is a value of date as a number like `1660847299055`.

I have the following option for the first chart.

```
      const option = {
        xAxis: {
          visible: false,
        },

        yAxis: {
          reversed: true,
          title: {
            text: 'Deviation',
          },
          startOnTick: false,
          endOnTick: false,
          min: 0,
          softMax: 15,
        },
      }
```

[image]

As the second chart said, I don't care about the relations of x values between those three red, green, and blue lines. They should be stretched from start to end.

How can I implement this?

Comment: I assume, they don't share the same x values?

Comment: They have x values, but it doesn't matter what x values each one has. They just should be stretched to the same starting point and the same last endpoint.

Comment: Do they have the same amount of x values?

Comment: No, they don't have the same amount of x values. They are pretty different.

Comment: A possible solution is to have multiple x axes, one per dataset, since you don't show them. Please add the data for the example for a more specific answer.

Comment: @hotcakedev Take a look at my update below. It has tips on how to operate on series data and what forms they have.  You will be able to adjust to what you want when you understand how series data is generated.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution based on the multiple x-axes idea (still don't know if it fits the OP's data format). The idea is to provide each series with its own x axis which will automatically adapt to the min and max of the data in that series. This works since none of the x axes are intended to be displayed.

```js
const data1 = [[1262304000000,0.7537],[1262563200000,0.6951],[1262649600000,0.6925],[1262736000000,0.697],[1262822400000,0.6992],[1262908800000,0.7007],[1263168000000,0.6884],[1263254400000,0.6907],[1263340800000,0.6868],[1263427200000,0.6904],[1263513600000,0.6958],[1263772800000,0.696],[1263859200000,0.7004],[1263945600000,0.7077],[1264032000000,0.7111],[1264118400000,0.7076],[1264377600000,0.7068],[1264464000000,0.7101],[1264550400000,0.7107],[1264636800000,0.7144],[1264723200000,0.7161]];
const data2 = [[1262649600000,0.625],[1262736000000,0.607],[1262908800000,0.62007],[1263254400000,0.64907]];
const data3 = [[1263427200000,0.6404],[1263513600000,0.6158],[1263772800000,0.636],[1263945600000,0.6077]];

new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: "chart1" },
    title: { text: "True x" },
    series: [
        {
            data: data1
        },
        {
            data:data2
        },
        {
            data: data3
        },
    ],
    xAxis: { type: "datetime", visible: false},
});

new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: "chart2" },
    title: { text: "Streched" },
    series: [
        {
            data: data1,
            xAxis: 0
        },
        {
            data:data2,
            xAxis: 1
        },
        {
            data: data3,
            xAxis: 2
        },
    ],
    xAxis: [
        { type: "datetime", visible: false},
        { type: "datetime", visible: false},
        { type: "datetime", visible: false},
    ]
});
```

```html
<div id="chart1" style="display:inline-block;height:90vh; width: 45vw"></div>
<div id="chart2" style="display:inline-block;height:90vh; width: 45vw"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.2/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine but why couldn't he/she  just have a value a linear x point and use a tool tip for the values ?

Comment: @PeterMoore I am not sure I understand ... are you thinking about changing the x values of the data points that are fed to highcharts? That would certainly be a solution and would have a larger applicability.

Comment: I guess i don't understand what the 'op' x value does, does it matter in this case so why care what it stands for. you can have 3 series s1 [[1,10], [5,20]] s2 = [[1, 40], [5,30]] and s3 [[1,1], [2,2],[3,3] , [4,4], [5,5]]  and arrive at the same stretched 3 line.  you just annotate with the hover. because a stretched x line cant label 3 series can it ? Still think your answer is cool. i would just do it the simpler way

Comment: Ah now i see it.  Yeh i thought you were merging 2 graphs.  Facepalm.  i would accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the `chart` handle you got after creating the chart you need to add a series for each line

```
 chart.addSeries({

            name: 'series name',
            type: 'line',
            data: [11,2,33,4,55,6,77,8]
          
        });
```

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#addSeries

Also `chart` has a member called `chart.series` for each line. You can play with this in the browser's debugging tool console window to understand whats going on. You can iterate over that array to interact with the data and modify or add to it.

[image]

Check out `xData` and `yData` data has X and Y components.  so adding data can be of the from value only `[10,20,30,40]` or timeseries `[[2020,10],[2021,20],[2022,30] ..]` x is year y is value.

To change the data completely you need to find which line and use `setData`

```js
for(let s of chart.series){
    if ( s.name == "series name"){
        let data = [NEW DATA];
        s.setData(data);
        
    }
    s.update()
}
//chart.redraw()
```

I would recommend [reading this page](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series) from highcharts about series data and experimenting with it in the browsers Inspector window.